# Pytorch, TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision

This is probably a beginner question, but nevertheless: When running an image classifier build with pytorch, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/pytorch/kanji_torch.py", line 47, in <module>
    network = Network()
  File "/pytorch/kanji_torch.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
  File "/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 233, in __init__
    False, _pair(0), groups, bias)
  File "/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 32, in __init__
    out_channels, in_channels // groups, *kernel_size))
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I define the network class like this:

```
class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 5)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 5 * 5, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 640)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(640, 3756)
```

Pretty sure that I imported all the relevant pytorch library modules correctly. 
(import torch.nn as nn and
import torch)

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: No, sorry that was a mistake, and I fixed it

Comment: Traceback seems to point file `/pytorch/blitz.py` (btw I'm intrigued by `/pytorch/.py` filename). In the code you pasted the class is named `Network` but the traceback speak about `Net`. Have you updated stuff before pasting code ?

Comment: that was sloppy on my side. I had two scipts with the same problem. I had them switched up, and thought I changed all the wrong names. The sloppiness has been edited out now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a problem with your pytorch version, when I run the code:

```
class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 5)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 5 * 5, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 640)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(640, 3756)
print(network)
```

The output is:

```
Network (
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (pool): MaxPool2d (size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), dilation=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (pool2): MaxPool2d (size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), dilation=(1, 1))
  (conv3): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (fc1): Linear (1600 -> 512)
  (fc2): Linear (512 -> 640)
  (fc3): Linear (640 -> 3756)
)
```

I would suggest to update/reinstall pytorch.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! I had a similar problem with torch.Variable, which is also solved now.